# How to fix map rendering multiple times in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component, Map, where I am attempting to use the [Jsvectormap](https://jvm-docs.vercel.app/) library to display a map. The problem is the map is showing up several times. I am struggling to see why the map would appear 3 times since I only call the Map component once. Any ideas on how to fix it so there is only 1 map appearing?

Here is the `Map.jsx` component:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./Map.css";
import jsVectorMap from "jsvectormap";
import "jsvectormap/dist/maps/world-merc.js";

function Map() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const map = new jsVectorMap({
      selector: "#map",
      map: "world_merc"
    });
  }, []);

  return <div id="map" />;
}

export default Map;
```

The `Map.css` file is currently empty, and the `App.js` file looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Map from './components/Map/Map'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Map />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Note the 3 maps appearing on the screen:

[image: 3 maps]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In development, with [`StrictMode`](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode) since version 18, React mounts, unmounts, and then mounts components on the initial render to check for bugs, and "non correct React code".

In the `Map` component's `useEffect`, you need a clean-up function, to destroy the map and remove it from the DOM before the component gets unmounted.

Otherwise, a component being designed to get mounted multiple times, you register a new map per mount.

Find below an example of how you would fix your issue. Notice the comments as well:

```
function Map() {
  // Used a ref instead of using the id as you did:
  const mapRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const mapElement = mapRef.current;
    const map = new jsVectorMap({
      selector: mapElement,
      map: "world_merc"
    });

    return () => {
      map.destroy();
      // destroy() doesn't seem to remove the map, that's why the DOM mutation:
      mapElement.innerHTML = "";
    };
  }, []);

  return <div ref={mapRef} />;
}
```

[image]